# Submit on enter key in phpMyAdmin not working any more

Tags: phpmyadmin

Yesterday I was able to submit in phpMyAdmin 4.2.12 with keys command, option and enter, e.g. in SQL query field or in edit row "mode".

I just found out this doesn't work any more, nothing happens when trying this.

Maybe I change something in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` or any other file.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Which browser? did you try with another browser?

Comment: @MarcDelisle I found out that my phpMyAdmin version is too old. This version seems not to support that. I mixed it up with an other database.